# Will there be object slicing in this case?

Tags: c++, class, reference

given the next code:

```
class A {
      // ...
};

class B : public A {
      // ...
};
```

And:

```
A a;   
B b;    
A& ab = b;   
ab = a;
```

Will be a slicing in the last line of this code? Why?

Comment: The treacherous case

Comment: @SmitYcyken What are you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will not be slicing. But there will be called the copy assignment operator for the class A due to the static type of the reference `ab`.

Consider the following program

```
#include <iostream>

struct A 
{
    A & operator =( const A & )
    {
        std::cout << "A::operator = is called" << std::endl;
        return *this;    
    }
};

struct B : A 
{
    B & operator =( const B & )
    {
        std::cout << "B::operator = is called" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    A a;   
    B b;    
    A &ab = b;   
    ab = a; 

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
A::operator = is called
```

You may not reassign a reference such a way that it would refer another object.

Comment: @DevSolar The question is not about what is slicing. The question is about whether in this example there will be slicing.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow All the members of `b` that declared in `B` will copy to `ab`?

Comment: @StackUser There will not be any copy. ab is a reference to b. There is not created any new object.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, you duplicated an already existed answer. 5 years old answer: Thus, the line a_ref = b1 will call the assignment operator of A, not that of B. And yours:  there will be called the copy assignment operator for the class A due to the static type of the reference ab.

Comment: @SmitYcyken Five years ago i was not at SO.:) I am a beginner.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, nu i slavno =)